# Fetch single record and return plain string to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Please check my Controller & View part. Here i am passing few row and single column using ViewBag to my view. That's why i needed to use foreach to display any value. I only want a single row value as string and want to display it from view without using foreach. Please tell me how can i return a simple string to my view without having foreach.

My Controller:

```
ViewBag.SearchedUsersTable = ctx.SearchedUsers.Where(x => x.SearchedUserID == SearchedUserID.SearchedUserID).ToList();
```

My View:

```
@if (ViewBag.SearchedUsersTable != null)
{
  foreach (var item in ViewBag.SearchedUsersTable)
{
  @item.EbayUsername;
}
}
```

Comment: Why you don't you use model ?

Comment: u mean use model in view?

Comment: Yes. Because you have a list there of searched users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `FirstOrDefault` method on the collection you have.

```
@if (ViewBag.SearchedUsersTable != null)
{
  var user= (ViewBag.SearchedUsersTable as List<SearchedUser>..FirstOrDefault();
  if (user != null)
  {
     <p>@user.EbayUsername</p>
  }    
}
```

**But**, If you actually need only item(row) in the view, i strongly recommend passing only that from the view. Why to query all the records in the action method ?

```
ViewBag.SingleUserName= ctx.SearchedUsers
                           .Where(x => x.SearchedUserID == SearchedUserID.SearchedUserID)
                           .Select(s=>s.EbayUsername)
                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

And in the view

```
<p>@ViewBag.SingleUserName</p>
```

Comment: Controller returning ToList() few more rows. i have to display only single value from that which called "EbayUsername"

Comment: You want to display a single row or multiple rows with single column ? Your current code does the later.

Comment: Thanks second part helps me